# Contradictory Hechsherim

Tags: kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, trust-neemanut

I've noticed for some time that, especially on imported foods, there are often multiple Hechsherim, and that they sometimes contradict one another.  It might not surprise me if a foreign product were marked with a Hechsher that a certifier on the importing end were stricter about (eg., a Hechsher on the importing end might be stricter about the temperature required for wine to be considered Mevushal and put a caveat on its label warning people that it's only Mevushal according to some, although it's still Kosher, even though the Rav HaMachshir at the exporting end labeled it Mevushal).

But I've seen many imported food products bearing Kosher for Passover certification from the Kashruth agency on the importing end, even though the Rav HaMachshir on the exporting end clearly marked the product "Not for Passover Use" (in the originating country's language).

How can a Kashruth agency on the importing end certify something *more leniently* than the agent they are trusting to have done the inspection, when they themselves did not observe the food processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be a few reasons for this, but predominantly, it can be one of two things:

1) The original certifier certifies it year round, and did not do anything to certify it for passover, but the importing certifier actually did visit and make a passover run. The original packaging was left in place for the production, however.

This especially can happen where products are imported into Israel, where in the originating country there was insufficient demand to justify a passover run, and only the import order justified it.

2) The importing certifier reviewed the process with the original certifier and found that whatever concern lead the original certifier to not certify it for passover was not a stringency that the importing certifier holds was necessary.

An example for number 2 would be that some certifiers require all passover ingredients to be certified, and will not rely on general industry practices, that lets, for example [cocoa power](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/general/52723/alert-the-shufra-baking-cocoa-crisis.html), without passover certification. Another example would be a certification that requires a Mashgiach for all passover certified productions, even if the ingredients and process are themselves not problematic.

Answer (score 2):

This is very common on imports from Israel certified by the Edah Hachareidis. The Edah certifies only staples for Pesach use. It is very common to see Passover cookies (matza meal or the like) in Israel with multiple Passover hashgachot and an Edah stamp which specifically states "For year round use."

Comment: In fact, i think the edah *only* specifies "for year round use" if someone else certified it for pesach but i'm not sure so i left it out of the answer.

Comment: Everything you write is true, but have you seen it applied to imported products? Sounds like a situation that would apply to native products.

Comment: I was in Israel all of last year including Pesach but I'm almost certain that I've seen that on Israeli products imported to the US

Comment: I've definitely seen it on Israeli products imported to the US.